# OracleDb. Ошибка при выполнении запроса: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2

Tags: node.js, oracle

Пытаюсь из формы подтянуть данные и вставить в БД Оракл, но возвращается ошибка:

> NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2

Код:

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
app.post('/newInput', function(req, res) {
    var insert = "INSERT INTO KFEDOROV.ISSUES_TABLE VALUES ('"+
    req.body.reqNo+
    "', '"+
    req.body.entity+
    "', '"+ 
    req.body.userId+ 
    "', '"+ 
    req.body.newValue+ 
    "', '"+
    req.body.userId+ 
    "', '"+
    req.body.userOrgUai+ 
    "', 'NEW','"+ 
    req.body.oldValue+ 
    "');";


    oracledb.getConnection(
        {
            user: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            connectString: 'connection'
        },
        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute(insert, { autoCommit: true}, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                        doRelease(connection);
                        return;
                    } else {
                            console.log(result.rows);
                            doRelease(connection);
                    }
                }
            )


                function doRelease(connection)
                {
                connection.close(
                    function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        console.error(err.message);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации [`connection.execute`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#-425-connectionexecute) указываются четыре аргумента:

```
execute(String sql, [Object bindParams, [Object options,]] function(Error error, [Object result]){});
```

При вызове с тремя аргументами второй принимается за `bindParams` — переменные привязки, которых в Вашем запросе, судя по всему, нет. Ошибка связана с тем, что  `autoCommit` воспринимается как параметр запроса.

Попробуйте явно указать пустой массив параметров:

```
connection.execute(insert, [],  { autoCommit: true}, function(err, result) {
...
```

З.Ы. Рекоммендую посмотреть в документации примеры использования параметров запроса. Сейчас Вы добавляете значения в запрос с помощью конкатенации, что нежелательно по многим причинам, например:

- Передача параметров в строковом виде создает риск [SQL-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
- Параметризованные запросы оптимальнее т.к. выполняются по одному шаблону и не требуют времени на разбор/анализ.
- Значения, переданные в запрос могут содержать спецсимволы (запятые, точки с запятой, кавычки, служебные слова SQL и т.п.). В текущем виде такие значения приведут к ошибке при выполнении запроса и потребуют предварительной обработки. При передаче через `bindParams` об этом можно не думать.

Comment: Да, действительно, Вы правы, спасибо. Но теперь ошибка вылезла "ORA-00933: неверное завершение SQL-предложения", хотя, SQL-предложение верное)

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov Пожалуйста, рад что помогло!

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov попробуйте точку с запятой убрать в конце запроса, если не поможет, то можете задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо!)